# Logic for Stored Proc for selecting multiple comma separated values in parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a report  in which I have to select multiple comma separated values in parameter. When I put only query like

```
select 'DB1' DBName, C1, C2, C3 from DB1.T1 inner join DB1.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
where 'DB1' in (@SelectedDatabase)
 UNION ALL
select 'DB2' DBName, C1, C2, C3 from DB2.T1 inner join DB2.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
where 'DB2' in (@SelectedDatabase)
 UNION ALL
select 'DB3' DBName, C1, C2, C3 from DB3.T1 inner join DB3.T2 on T1.C4 = T2.C4
where 'DB3' in (@SelectedDatabase)
```

Report is working fine for multiple values. But when I put this logic into stored proc. For single value it
is working fine but for multiple value it is not working.
Can some one please help me in this .

1. logic for stored proc for accepting multiple comma separated values?
2. Is this possible i can make my stored proc dynamic in a way so that it takes database name dynamically (for every new database I don't have  to alter my proc each and every time).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that these two pieces of code are not the same...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Compared to...

```
SET @list = '1,2,3'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@list)
```

In the latter case, @list isn't a list of numbers, it's a single string.  It's treated as a list of 1 item, where that item is a string.

To be 'perfectly' generalised, you can write a table-valued-function (there are hundreds on the web) that takes a string and splits it into a table of values.  This enables you to do this...

```
WHERE 'DB1' IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.split(@list))
```

This is especially good where the list could have virtually any number of items, and each item be virtually any value.

In your case, however, your list is short, and is constrained to a very small number of possible enumerated values.  This means that you can 'cheat' slightly...

```
WHERE @list LIKE '%DB1%'

Or, if you want to be very rigorous...

WHERE ',' + @list + ',' LIKE '%,DB1,%'
```

If you have (or may use in the future) the split function, I'd use that approach just for consistency.

If you want a quick win, using LIKE in this way (On a constant/parameter), is perfectly fine in my opinion.

Comment: I am getting this error while doing this process.
I created function which will covert string into table and using that function in my stored proc. the error is :

**Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.**